# Quiero guardar y recuperar el valor seleccionado en un Spinner en SharedPreferences

Tags: spinner, sharedpreferences

Puedo traer los valores a otros componentes pero no al *Spinner*, este es mi código:

```
//Función que crea un archivo de preferencias
public void CargarPreferencia()
{
    SharedPreferences mispreferencias=getSharedPreferences("PrefeM", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    tecnicoMS.setText(mispreferencias.getString("tecnicoM",""));
    txtdate.setText(mispreferencias.getString("dateM",""));
    cliente.setText(mispreferencias.getString("clienteM",""));
    txtsucursal.setText(mispreferencias.getString("sucursalM",""));
}

//Función que guarda el estado del CheckBox para saber si se mandó el SMS y no volver a enviarlo
public void GuardarPreferencias()
{
//        String txtsel=tecnico.getSelectedItem().toString();

//        String tecselec= (String) tecnico.getSelectedItem();
//        String cliselec= (String) cliente.getSelectedItem();

    SharedPreferences mispreferencias=getSharedPreferences("PrefeM",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mispreferencias.edit();

    String valor10 = tecnico.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String valor20 = txtdate.getText().toString();
    String valor30 = cliente.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String valor40 = txtsucursal.getText().toString();

    editor.putString("tecnicoM",valor10);
    editor.putString("dateM",valor20);
    editor.putString("clienteM",valor30);
    editor.putString("sucursalM",valor40);
    editor.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para guardar la posición de un **item** del `Spinner` en un `SharedPreference`, utiliza el método `putInt()` del `SharedPreference`. Despues para obtener el valor del `SharedPreference`, utiliza el método `getInt()` del mismo.

```
int valor = tecnico.getSelectedItem(); 
editor.putInt("posicion", valor);
```

Para seleccionar la posición del item utiliza el método `setSelection()` del `Spinner`.

```
tecnico.setSelection(mispreferencias.getInt("posicion", 0));
```

Comment: Gracias David!!!

Comment: Hola, Disculpa, utilicé el código de como seleccionar un spinner en shared, pero me arroja un error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer ... ayuda por favor lo necesito y no se que hacer. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Puedes crear una nueva pregunta y agregar el codigo que te da el error.

Comment: No puedo crear una pregunta, sale que eh agotado mi limite de preguntas, lo siento, pero lo necesito

Comment: Hablemos desde esta sala de chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89786/discucion-entre-david-y-bloom

Answer (score 0):

Gustavo Giuffre: ¿Que serían "tecnicoMS", "txtdate","cliente" y "txtsucursal"? Son distintos Spinner's o son los elementos que componen un Spinner?

Comment: Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]